# Service worker: fetch from network after cache miss only if WiFi connection

Tags: javascript, http, caching, service-worker

I would like my service worker to adopt the following approach:

- consult the cache
- if cache hit, return cached resource
- else if WiFi, fetch resource from network
- else return error

I know about `navigator.onLine`, but this does not (as I understand it) differentiate connection type, and merely signifies that the client is online (by whatever means).

Is there a way of doing this in the service worker?  Even by some devious means?  For

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found [`navigator.connection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection), which seems to have been around for a while, but with patchy support.  Indeed, it is only [supported from desktop Chrome 61](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6338383617982464), so the Chrome browser from which I'm posting this does not support it.  On the other hand, it has apparently been supported for some time on Android Chrome, which is the context in which I need it.  See [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/network-information/) for a useful code snippet and live example.

So, to check for a WiFi connection, it would then be a case of checking whether the [`navigator.connection.type`](http://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#dfn-connection-types) property is set to 'wifi'.